# video tag element blocked by internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-video

ok so I have this html 5 code that works fine on chome and firefox but not on internet explorer(9):

```
<video width="60%" height="360" controls autoplay>
    <source src="video/video1_edit.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="video/video1_edit.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    <source src="video/video1_edit.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'>
    <object data="video/video1_edit.mp4" width="60%" height="360">
        <embed src="video/video1_edit.mp4" width="60%" height="360">
    </object>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <font color="red">Can't play video. Please Upgrade your browser.</font>
</video>
```

and every time I try it on IE all I get is a disable media player and it says: "Internet Explorer blocked an ActiveX control, so this page might not display correctly"

so how can I embed videos playable for internet explorer assuming that the user doesn't want or know how to change their ActiveX restrictions settings? and if is not asking too much make it playable in older versions as well.

EDIT:
@robertc was right, changing the default MIME types for the video types I was using solved the problem.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  Do you have the HTML5 DOCTYPE set?  `<video>` doesn't require an ActiveX control, so it seems that it's trying to fallback to the `<object>` tag, and the plug-in is getting blocked.

Comment: `<font>` tags?!  What is this 1999?  But wait, there's a `<video>` tag too, it can't be 1999.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I do have the doctype set to <!DOCTYPE html> and the IE version is 9.0.8112.16421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit F12, what does it say for browser mode and document mode?  It will need to say IE9 and IE9 Standards mode for `<video>` to work.  Do you have [Display intranet sites in compatibility mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/06/17/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults.aspx) checked?

Comment: yes both browser mode and intranet compatibility mode are set as you described.

Comment: @NeoZeroX21 OK, please upload your files somewhere

Comment: Already up:
[link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxxyH1Bh3XWzcFpXaUxSLVlLNE0&usp=sharing)

Comment: @NeoZeroX21 [Works fine for me](http://www.dotrob.com/demo/video.html). Have you set the `.mp4` MIME type on your server?

Comment: I have not, I am no the admin for the server but I will request the change and let you know.

Comment: the request came through and now it is working but as expected only for IE 9, older versions still block the object part which I will try to find a workaround for. Thanks for the help!